# Get accounts that have looged in with the same ip within ip loging table

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table such as:

```
memberid,time,ip
```

The his an ip history of all the ip's that have logged in and the associated account id they logged in with and their respective IP.

**Is there anyway with a single query that you can check if there are any IP's in the table that have logged into `> 1` account and if so, what `memberid's` has that IP logged into.**

I know how to restrict it to unique IP's by account using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT memberid,ip FROM iphistory
```

but unsure how I can check what memberid's share the same IP.

**Edit:** Updated to make it more clear.

Comment: Read up on using `WHERE` and/or `GROUP BY` clauses

Comment: What is the point of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be phrased as: "members that share the same ip". To determine that something like:

```
select ip
from T
group by ip
having count(distinct memberid) > 1
```

can be used. If you want the members that are associated with these ip's you can join the original table with that:

```
select distinct x.memberid, y.ip
from T as x
join (
    select ip
    from T
    group by ip
    having count(distinct memberid) > 1
) as y
    on x.ip = y.ip
```

I've added distinct since a member can log in from one ip several times.

Comment: Isn't that members that share the same ip (i.e. the second part of my answer)?

Comment: Ahh you're right. I stopped reading after the top part as I thought you misunderstood :)

Comment: Thanks, I removed the first part from the answer.

Comment: Testing the 2nd part that shows the users; shouldn't it use a `DISTINCT` on the first select?

Comment: I assume you used the original version (since you accepted the answer), I added distinct when I removed the first part.

Comment: I noticed you added distinct and I accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an ip address say "192.0.100.1" of member "myuser" and you want to check what all member that logged nto the system with same and check if other members who logged in using the same ip, then you could use where clause as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT memberid
FROM iphistory
WHERE ip = "192.0.100.1"
AND   memberid != 'myuser'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupby 
SELECT DISTINCT memberid,ip FROM iphistory GROUP BY ip;
**vote up** the answers that helped you the most!